# Ambiguity in oxidation state of phosphorus in H3PO3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state

Phosphorus(2.19) is less electronegative than hydrogen(2.20), so during calculation of oxidation state of phosphorus the oxidation state of hydrogen should be taken as-1 but in books it's taken as +1 why?

Comment: Saying that 2.19 is less than 2.2 is true, mathematically. But only.

Comment: Oxidation number has only a loose connection with electronegativity. It's counted based on rules and in this case not only for P, but all 15 group elements H bound to them is on +1.

Comment: Oxidation number is rather a convention for gray zones and this convention says that at a formal break of P-H bond in H3PO3 electron stays at P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several electronegativity scales. In the Pauling scale, H and P are at 2.1. In the Mulliken scale, H is at 2.2 and P at 2.3. In the Allred and Rochow scale, it is the contrary : H is at 2.2 and P at 2.1. These scales are contradictory for H and P. So it is necessary to choose for teaching purposes. And book authors have usually chosen +1 for H, because H is rarely at -1, and only in very reactive compounds like NaH.

Ref. : Michael O. Hurst, J. Chem. Ed. 79, June 2002. How we teach Molecular Structure to Freshmen.